# How do I make element tags adjust as screen switches from portrait to landscape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, orientation

I want to know how can I achieve this as I switch between the two orientation. I tried using margin or centerVertical but that would only keep it in center and not adjustable.

[how I desire my layout to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWCXt.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by adjust?

Comment: check this http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/ tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **layout-land** directory and design your landscape mode design in this directory and for portrait mode keep the design same as in **layout** directory. This will easily help to manage landscape and portrait different designs.

Like this:

```
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main.xml 
res/layout-port [Portrait Mode ]
main.xml
```

In Manifest.xml add orientation config changes to your Activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation​"
```

Now to set xml content to your activity override onConfigurationChanged method and set content like this:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);//This main.xml is in layout-land folder
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);//This main.xml is in layout folder
        }
    }
```